# Setup dask and jupyter on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, jupyter, dask

Aim to set up an ecosystem on Google Compute Engine consisting of dask and jupyterlab, wherein the dask cluster can be provisioned dynamically for a given task from jupyterlab and the cluster size can be customized

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.  What is it you are asking?  What have you tried?

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://medium.com/pangeo/pangeo-cloud-cluster-design-9d58a1bf1ad3)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Dask's cloud setup documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/cloud.html